# std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>) in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, winsock2

The other answers I read on this website didn't seem relevant to my issue. Anyway, in my mainwindow.cpp file I have a function that needs access to the ui namespace:

```
 do
    {
        intrecv= recv(s1, buffer, 10000,0);
        if(intrecv > 0)
        {
            recvData = buffer;
            ui->textEdit->setText("Connection occurred.\n");
        }   
    }while(intrecv > 0);
```

Here are my preprocessor commands:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <QString>
```

In my mainwindow.h file I prototyped the receive function as such:

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void receiveFunction();

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_lineEdit_returnPressed();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Then, in mainwindow.cpp, I called that receive function in a thread in another function:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    connectFunction();
    std::thread t1(receiveFunction);
    t1.detach();
}
```

An example you could try to replicate my problem is make a pushbutton and a textEdit field. Have the pushbutton's slot call a function that edits the textEdit field.

edit: I forgot to mention: for my mini example, don't just have it edit the textEdit field, have it receive data and edit the textEdit field.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to hint that there are multiple overloads of the `reveiveFunction` function, but that might be misleading (if the code above is correct). There are two things inherently wrong in the line:

```
std::thread t1(receiveFunction);
```

First is that you cannot take the address of a member function without providing the type qualification (and a member function does not decay to a pointer to member function). The second problem is that a non-static member function requires an object on which it will be called, which you are not providing. That statement can be fixed by doing:

```
std::thread t1(&MainWindow::receiveFunction, this);
```

That will correctly take the address of the member function, and provide the `this` pointer on which the function will be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, I saw this solution in another thread. Unfortunately, I get a runtime error when I try it. Edit: Just to be clear, it does compile.

Comment: @user3466884: Then you have another problem, but breaking this won't help you deal with the other problem. Are you destroying the `MainWindow` object before the thread completes?

Comment: Nope, didn't destroy the MainWindow object.

Comment: Ah, I see what the issue is. I named another thread in my program the same thing, which probably caused the error. However, the thread doesn't seem to be receiving any packets like I wanted it to.

Comment: Edit: Getting a runtime error again. It seems to be receiving data but stops working after some received data. Possibly has something to do with how I'm parsing the packets. Edit: Everything's working fine now.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Sometimes it works for a little while longer but usually it will get a runtime error after a few seconds.